# PHP Form - Need pastes information in textarea to keep formatting

Tags: php, sql, forms, rich-text-editor

I'm creating a PHP Form and part of the form users must copy and paste an essay into a . When we generate the results of the form all formatting is lost. All I need is for line breaks and/or double spacing to remain as the user sees it when they are submitting the form.

I've read about installing a HTML rich text editor, but I'm new to this and I can't find any straight answers for my situation.

Data entered into the form is received on our SQL and then posted to an HTML document we can download.

Comment: Two ideas:
1, Convert line breaks to `<br/>`
2, apply `<pre></pre>` around the text

Comment: @ppeterka do this on the php form or the HTML that renders the data from the form?

Comment: Well, technically you can put both in the uploading logic or the display logic.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with displaying: Just check the source code of the resulting page.

HTML does nto care about line breaks and also mangles whitespace.

So two easy solution comes up:

**Line breaks to `<br/>`**

```
echo str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $myInputText);
```

This converts the ordinary line breaks to line breaks understood by HTML. This can be done when **storing** the content - then no changes arte needed to the duisplaying part.

(Or you can put this into the displaying part too, and not change the upload logic.)

**Using `<pre></pre>`**

```
echo "<pre>$myInputText</pre>";
```

This applies all the whitespace formatting to the content, and is better ot put to the displaying part.

**Using your comment**

If I understood well what you'd like to achieve, this is the easiest:

```
$HTMLBODY .= "<h2>ESSAY</h2>";  //note the </h2>!
$HTMLBODY .= "<p><pre>" . $_POST['essay'] . "<pre></p>";
```

Also, at the same time, **be careful** with using unsanitized `$POST['']` entries: someone with a bit of hackish instinct might do crazy things to your site...

Comment: This is my posting code:
$HTMLBODY .= "<h2>ESSAY</h3>";
$HTMLBODY .= "<p>" . $_POST['essay'] . "</p>";

The form label is 'essay'